# Decreasing NSTimer interval every time it runs

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer

I want my `NSTimer` to speed up each time it's run:

```
-(void)runtimer {
   int delay = delay - 1;
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(delay) 
                                    target:self 
                                  selector:@selector(timerTriggered:) 
                                  userInfo:nil 
                                   repeats:YES];

}
```

But this doesn't work. How can I make the delay keep getting smaller and smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the delay somewhere, like in the class interface or as a static variable.

Also, create a new timer every time, instead of having it repeat.

```
int delay = INITIAL_DELAY;

-(void)runtimer{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)(delay--) target:self selector:@selector(runTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Comment: The timer is indeed being created anew each time, and given a different method, called `timerTriggered:`, to fire.

Answer (score 3):

I [needed this myself](https://blog.compeople.eu/apps/?p=368) and wrote a component [CPAccelerationTimer (Github)](https://github.com/yangmeyer/CPAccelerationTimer):

```
[[CPAccelerationTimer accelerationTimerWithTicks:20
    totalDuration:10.0
    controlPoint1:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0) // ease in
    controlPoint2:CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0)
    atEachTickDo:^(NSUInteger tickIndex) {
        [self timerTriggered:nil];
    } completion:^{
        [self timerTriggered:nil];
    }]
run];
```

This calls `-timerTriggered:` 20 times, spread out over 10 seconds, with ever-decreasing delays (as specified by the given Bézier curve).

Answer (score 1):

Every time this method is run, you make a new variable called `delay`, then try to set it to itself minus 1. This is Undefined Behavior (the variable was not initialized to anything), and is likely to result in a garbage value for `delay`.*

You need to store the delay in an instance variable.

```
- (void) runTimer {
    // You are declaring a new int called |delay| here.
    int delay = delay - 1;
    // This is not the same |delay| that you have declared in your header.
    // To access that variable, use:
    delay = delay - 1;
```

---

*[A sinus infestation by evil-aligned supernatural beings](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) is also a possibility.

Comment: I actually am but i didn't post it here just because i forget to say that. So even after i have it in the header it still doesn't work...

Comment: The snippet that you posted has a local variable shadowing the ivar then.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the fire interval of the timer once you have created it. If you want a different interval you must invalidate the previous timer (hence you should keep a reference to it), and create a new timer with a different interval.

Comment: This code isn't trying to change the interval; it is, in fact, creating a new timer each time.

Comment: …but the code to create the timers passes in `YES` for the `repeats:` parameter, which means that there'll be an awful lot of timers running by the end of the infinite loop.

Comment: @Rob: I assume (perhaps erroneously) that they're being invalidated in `timerTriggered:`.